# VS 2013 - How To Add Features To An Existing Web Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I just created an empty web application in Visual Studio 2013.

From then on, how would I add MVC and/or Web API capabilities similar to how we're able to specify those when creating a project?

In another somewhat similar case, I created an MVC app with no authentication (i.e., users don't log in to the site). How do I modify/set up this project to implement individual users and add Web API capabilities?

Comment: Start off by adding the required NuGet packages to your project (such as `Microsoft ASP.NET MVC`). For learning create a non-empty web application and see what packages are installed. If you install packages manually in your project you might have to tweak your Web.config too.

Comment: I've tried that. It adds references and writes a few settings on the Web.config. They don't write the much needed AccountController (and its views), the startup Models, files that go in the App_Start folder, etc.

Comment: If you need all of that, start with a basic project.  Just adding an assembly does not automatically create all of those items for you, that is the VS project template doing that for you.  Otherwise, you will need to create your own controllers folder, create your own AccountController, etc. This is accomplished by right clicking in the solution and selecting Add -> new item.

Comment: I guess the answer is - you can't. Yes, you'll get reference and scripts added but you'll have to write all the code for account management and application startup.